# Httpwebrequest with google forms(GoogleFormsToolkitLibrary)

Tags: c#, google-forms

I am using GoogleFormsToolkitLibrary from nuget to retrieve a google forms data. This work fine but without any restrictiion. But when I create a google forms that restrict only my organization it failed to load the data with error saying `InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements` 
I want to know how can I connect to the restricted google forms with my Internet Explore. Because my Internet Explore already sign in to the organization.

My code:

```
GoogleFormsToolkitLibrary.GoogleFormsToolkitLibrary ggf = new GoogleFormsToolkitLibrary.GoogleFormsToolkitLibrary();
var googleFormLink ="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/" +"test" +"/viewform?test";
var googleFormsToolkitLibrary = ggf;
var result = await googleFormsToolkitLibrary.LoadGoogleFormStructureAsync(googleFormLink);
```

I am also try to use

`HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy();`

Comment: URL parameters are at the end of the URL after a question mark.  So yo uneed something like this : "viewform?source=abc".

Comment: @jdweng I already insert a url. It's not why it's not working.

Comment: The error says the parameter "SOURCE IS NULL"

Comment: @jdweng Sorry I type the wrong error. Already change it

Comment: Usually with Google they require an ID as a parameter in the URL.  Did you forget to put the id into the URL?

Comment: @jdweng Okay,Where do I need to put my ID?

Comment: [_**Important** We don't recommend that you use `HttpWebRequest` for new development. Instead, use the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class._](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-5.0#remarks)